# MSMQ Firewall Ports

Tags: firewall

I'd like to know what ports need to be opened on a firewall in order to allow public read access to an MSMQ private queue.

I'm aware that Microsoft publishes a list of ports here:  http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;178517

But I only want to open the ports that are specificially required in order to connect to the MSMQ instance and read messages from a private queue (no Active Directory involved).

Comment: okay, you can do it, but are you sure you want to be doing this. Your opening up this port to attack from anonymous users from the whole internet.  Now, with Microsoft's track record of zero days, patch tuesday etc etc, do really want to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I eventually found this article: [How To Configure a Firewall for MSMQ Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183293)
. And this article: [Clear the way - MSMQ coming through](http://blogs.msdn.com/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/04/29/clear-the-way-msmq-coming-through.aspx)

To recap, you need ports 135, 2103 and 2105 open in order to read a message from a public queue.

Answer (score 1):

From that article, it looks like all those ports are required, with the exception of port 389, which it indicates is for Active Directory.

Comment: Thanks Adam, but I'm specifically looking for the specific ports that are required to read from a MSMQ queue on a public facing website. I don't want to open any unnecessary ports.

Comment: I guess you could test it by just enabling/disabling firewall rules and see how it goes. I suspect though that all those ports are needed regardless of the implementation scenario.

Answer (score 1):

MSMQ requires TCP ports

- 135
- 2103
- 2105

(my personal experience)

Answer (score 1):

To only send (push) messages from server to server you need TCP 1801.

To remote receive (pull) messages from a server you need TCP 135, 2103, and 2105.

Usually you should not do remote received with MSMQ. If you have MSMQ configured in workgroup mode then only TCP 1801 is required.